# Multiple entries in WHERE or use Use * in WHERE * and use LIKE SQL

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I am supposed to get everything in 2 columns of a table that starts with 'a'. Please suggest modifications to this. (Searchbox.Text = 'a')

I am using ASP .Net and language is Visual Basic, while the database is SQL Server Compact. I have tried the below to obtain different results.

Code A:

```
"SELECT * FROM [Table Name] WHERE [Column1] LIKE '" + SearchTextBox.Text + "%'" AND [Column2] LIKE '" + SearchTextBox.Text + "%'"
```

Code B:

```
"SELECT * FROM [Table Name] WHERE * LIKE '" + SearchTextBox.Text + "%'"
```

Comment: [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)!!! This screams "SQL injection."

Comment: First suggestion is to use parameterization...  And 'Code B' is not valid SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to use " or " rather than " and " as " and " will give you only the columns where an " a " is in both columns...

You'd be much better creating a stored procdure wih a parameter and binding to that. You code will not be subject to injection attack which it currently is.

HTH

Comment: Thank You guys, I understand I gotta use 'OR' rather than 'AND'. Everyone was right so everyone will get chocolates(just joking)and so I ticked everyone's answer. But I guess I can't do it. Anything I can do for you?

Comment: Stored Procs aren't magically immune to injection but do make it harder. Even better is to use parameterised queries (and compile them if you're concerned about the performance boost from SPs)

Comment: And yet I don't understand why the answers are getting downvoted. Can anyone explain me please why. And also I used : "SELECT  * FROM [TableName] WHERE [ColumnName1] LIKE '" + SearchTextBox.Text + "%' OR [ColumnName2] LIKE '" + SearchTextBox.Text + "%'" and it returns a something starting with S. Why so?

Comment: @Basic: It requires 15 reputation and I used this site only for about 2 hrs, though I probably signed up lots of days before.

Comment: Are you sure `SearchTextBox.Text` equals `a`? If it's blank, it will match all records. as to the downvotes, you sometimes get idiots or perhaps someone thought our answers weren't detailed enough - maybe even other answerers trying to promote their own answer by downvoting others. It's only a minor annoyance and will recitfy itself over time

Comment: @Basic - I'm guessing the downvotes are because the answers, while they may be valid, still perpetuate the vulnerability to SQL injection attacks, and don't make any mention of how to avoid that. <shrug>

Comment: @Basic Don't worry about that, I have already added If TextBox.Text <> "" Then (all the subs) End If so not a problem. Thanks for your answers and sorry for late response as I went to sleep later. It was around 4 am here. Thanks again. and BTW I started adding parameters. Thanks for that

Comment: No worries. May I also suggest you consider using... `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MyString)` to check for empty strings - otherwise, what is someone puts a space in there? or passes in `null` (`Nothing` in VB)

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    [Table Name] 
WHERE 
       [Column1] LIKE '" + SearchTextBox.Text + "%'" 
    or [Column2] LIKE '" + SearchTextBox.Text + "%'"
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean ...

```
SELECT  *
FROM    [Table Name]
WHERE   [Column1] LIKE '" + SearchTextBox.Text + "%'"
OR      [Column2] LIKE '" + SearchTextBox.Text + "%'"
```

?

Note that I'm using an `OR` instead of an `AND` - This is pretty fundamental stuff, so if this is your problem, you should read up on [Boolean operations](http://www.csa.com/help/Search_Tools/boolean_operators.html)